# Displaying pdf after compilation in WinEdt 10.3

Tags: pdftex, winedt, texify

I would like to ask, why PDFTeXify shows pdf page *after compiling* while
PDFLaTeX only compiles and saves *.pdf output do the directory in WinEdt 10.3.
How do I make PDFLaTeX to also show that pdf page it creates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `Execution Modes` in the `Options`menu, select the   `pdflatex` Console Application and select `Start Viewer`, like this:

[image]

Comment: What is `Forward Search` checked there ?

Comment: You can go  from a place in the latex code to its result in the .pdf.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: when checked `Forward Search` a red line appears in new window and PC beeps loudly after compilation with XeTeX.

Comment: No idea what happens. What's your OS?

Comment: Windows 8.1  ...............   ..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know this version of Windows. I'm under Windows 7, and as far as I know, there's no problem either under Windows 10.