# Forward Search in execution modes doesn't work well in WinEdt 10.3

Tags: xetex, errors, compiling, winedt

When I enable in `Execution Modes` the sub-field `Forward Search` under XeTeX in WinEdt 10.3 and then
compile my .tex file, I get the following error immediately after compilation
(i.e. without ever clicking on anything):

[image]

The procedure is given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557951/displaying-pdf-after-compilation-in-winedt-10-3).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use forward search better use as pdf viewer e.g. sumatra. With adobe viewer it doesn't work well.

Apart from this you will have to adapt the DDE name in execution modes, tab "pdf viewer". R17 is probably too old, I have currently R20:

[image]

Comment: Well, I have found that field but I do not know how do I update it . Just entering `AcroviewR20` ? I.e. just rewriting R17 ? How did you get know that I'm using R17 ?

Comment: if you have the newest acrobat reader. The value changes every year.

Comment: Your error message shows "AcroviewR17".

Comment: Well, how do I update it, just by rewriting R17 to R20 in that field ? Or shall I update AR first ?

Comment: I have written there `R20` and the error ceases but I still do not know what the `Forward Search` is supposed to do.

Comment: read the winedt help.

Comment: I've oppened it but I couldn't find the relevant page.

Comment: I would recommend  using SumatraPDF as a pdf viewer with WinEdt: it doesn't lock the pdfs, so you can recompile instantly, and is much lighter than Adobe's viewer.

Comment: I have to give up the search forward option. I'm too much get used to AR  ...

Comment: Yet it has a much longer starting time (uses 402 Mo on my disk, vs 24 Mo for SumatraPDF!)

Comment: @Bernard But still, I would like to understand what that `Forward Search` field, when checked, is supposed to do when it works. EDIT: what is "Mo" ?

Comment: The compiler creates  a a new auxiliary file with extension synctex.gz which contains information on the structure of the document, which enables *ad hoc*  viewers to find, from a spot in the source code, to find  (via a shortcut) the corresponding spot in the resulting .pdf, and vice-versa for inverse search. SumatraPDF was designed from its origin to be compatible with this mechanism.